# Map projections for each quadrant of the globe

Tags: coordinate-system

I am using an xarray data and matplotlib to plot it before export

This is the xarr data used

```
<xarray.DataArray 't2m' (latitude: 361, longitude: 720)>
array([[273.9, 273.9, 273.9, ..., 273.9, 273.9, 273.9],
       [274.1, 274.1, 274.1, ..., 274.1, 274.1, 274.1],
       [274.5, 274.5, 274.5, ..., 274.5, 274.5, 274.5],
       ...,
       [220.6, 220.6, 220.6, ..., 220.6, 220.6, 220.6],
       [221.6, 221.6, 221.6, ..., 221.6, 221.6, 221.6],
       [223. , 223. , 223. , ..., 223. , 223. , 223. ]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * latitude    (latitude) float64 90.0 89.5 89.0 88.5 ... -89.0 -89.5 -90.0
  * longitude   (longitude) float64 -180.0 -179.5 -179.0 ... 178.5 179.0 179.5
    step        timedelta64[ns] 03:00:00
    valid_time  datetime64[ns] 2020-09-14T03:00:00
Attributes:
    standard_name:  air_temperature
```

The longitude range is from -180 to +180. If I use the below data with projections the image produced is correct.

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs


imgDpi = 100
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(512/imgDpi, 512/imgDpi), dpi=imgDpi) #to convert from inches to px
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection=ccrs.epsg(3857))
ax.imshow(xarr, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), origin='upper', cmap='viridis') 
ax.axis('off')
fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
fig.savefig('unsliced.png', format="png", transparent=True, dpi=imgDpi)
```

[image: image produced using unsliced data]

But if I slice the data into four quadrants and plot, there is an issue with projection

```
topLeft = xarr.sel(longitude=slice(-180, 0), latitude=slice(90, 0))
topRight = xarr.sel(longitude=slice(0, 180), latitude=slice(90, 0))
bottomLeft = xarr.sel(longitude=slice(-180, 0), latitude=slice(0, -90))
bottomRight = xarr.sel(longitude=slice(0, 180), latitude=slice(0, -90))

axTL = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1, projection=ccrs.epsg(3857))
axTL.imshow(topLeft, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), origin='upper', cmap='viridis') 
axTL.axis('off')

axTR = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2, projection=ccrs.epsg(3857))
axTR.imshow(topRight, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), origin='upper', cmap='viridis')
axTR.axis('off')

axBL = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3, projection=ccrs.epsg(3857))
axBL.imshow(bottomLeft, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), origin='upper', cmap='viridis')
axBL.axis('off')

axBR = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4, projection=ccrs.epsg(3857))
axBR.imshow(bottomRight, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), origin='upper', cmap='viridis')
axBR.axis('off')
```

[image: Sliced data]

Answer (score 0):

I applied Global ccrs and set the min-max for cmap along with extent.

```
globe_w = ccrs.Globe(datum="WGS84",ellipse="WGS84") 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(globe=globe_w))
ax1.imshow(data1, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(globe=globe_w), origin='upper', cmap='viridis', vmin=minTemp, vmax=maxTemp, extent=(-180, 180, 90, -90))
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.set_aspect(2)
```

[image: Global CCRS]